# mysql subtract two rows and places into Alias

Tags: mysql, diff

I have a table transaction with columns: date, approved.
I'm trying to subtract two rows (approved) together and put the results into an alias called approved_diff

I'm using:

**SELECT date, approved FROM transaction;**

| date | approved |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-24 09:43:00 | 10 |
| 2022-06-24 09:45:00 | 15 |
| 2022-06-24 09:50:00 | 50 |
| 2022-06-24 09:52:00 | 51 |
| 2022-06-24 09:57:00 | 56 |

what I would like is:

| date | approved | approved_diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-24 09:43:00 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-06-24 09:45:00 | 15 | 5 |
| 2022-06-24 09:50:00 | 16 | 1 |
| 2022-06-24 09:52:00 | 20 | 4 |
| 2022-06-24 09:57:00 | 22 | 2 |

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use the `LAG()` analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT date, approved,
       approved - LAG(approved, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS approved_diff
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can use a correlated subquery in place of `LAG()`:

```sql
SELECT date, approved,
       approved - (SELECT approved FROM yourTable t2
                   WHERE t2.date < t1.date
                   ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS approved_diff
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY date;
```